# Create A New, Stopped Process in C

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I am looking to create a new process through something like fork() and exec(), but immediately stop it (it begins in the state of SIGSTOP).  I'm hoping there's a system call capable of doing this or something else.  I've looked and can't really find anything.  The issue with fork() -> exec() -> SIGSTOP is the child process could run for a while before it receives the SIGSTOP (race condition).  Thanks!

Comment: You could just stop after the call to fork (since the same program continues to execute after a fork).

Comment: I was hoping to start and stop processes after creating them in this way, meaning I would need separate logic for the first time and the following ones.  Aka I would have two branches in my program with one being to exec and start, then stop and the other to be to start then stop.  It's for a process scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Under linux, you can use the `clone` syscall with the `CLONE_STOPPED` option.

(2) For other unix systems that don't have this [but may have an alternate], you could have the child send *itself* a `SIGSTOP` via the `kill` syscall *immediately* after the `fork`.

For (2), you may need to do a bit more setup than that, possibly in the parent.

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for the clone and clone_stopped combination.  Thanks!